# Как выбрать текст мeжду определенными символами?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вот такая строка

```
 worldTime(1492783520000,document.getElementById("worldTime"));
```

вот так пробую

`preg_match_all('worldTime\((.+?)\,', $url, $arr);`

но не работает.
Мне нужно извлечь только время

Comment: Если будет свободная минута, пожалуйста, проголосуйте за [полезные отвтеты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно извлечь цифры после `worldTime(`, используйте

```
$res = "";
$s = ' worldTime(1492783520000,document.getElementById("worldTime"));';
if (preg_match('~worldTime\((\d+)~', $s, $m)) {
     $res = $m[1];
}
echo $res; 
// => 1492783520000
```

[См. PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/JBBedE) и [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/b0I98y/1).

Регулярное выражение находит `worldTime(`, потом (с помощью `(\d+)`) захватывает в 1-ю подмаску 1 и более цифр.

Можно использовать версию без захватывающей подмаски, если использовать `\K`, обнуляющий текст текущего совпадения:

```
if (preg_match('~worldTime\(\K\d+~', $s, $m)) {
     $res = $m[0];
}
```

[Демо второго регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/b0I98y/2).

Answer (score 0):

Вы не задали ограничители.

```
preg_match_all('@worldTime\((.+?)\,@', $url, $arr);
```